# output file is created but nothing is printed

Tags: c, file, printf, output

Here is a code in the main.

```
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  fp = fopen("outputfile.txt", "w");
  fprintf(fp, "%s", "|# of elem||  Sum  ||      Range      ||   Mean          ||Variance||Standard Deviation|\n");
```

And I have this function that is called later in the main.

```
void produceOutput(FILE *fp, int totalNumOfElem, int sum, int min, int max,     double mean, double variance, double stanDev){
  fprintf(fp, "|%9d||%7d||%7d to%7d||%9.3f||%8.3f||%18.3f|\n", totalNumOfElem, sum, min, max, mean,variance, stanDev);

}
```

Then at the way end of the main function, I have

```
fclose(fp);
```

A file called `outputfile.txt` is actually created in the folder. But nothing is printed out. Now I'm a little confused because compiled it once and it worked! The data correctly printed out in the `outputfile.txt`
Then I tried it a second time, a third, fourth, NOTHING. Empty!
Why isn't it printing out anymore?
Is there something I need to know about `fprintf()`?
I didn't change anything in the code. 
What is the problem??
Do I need to delete `outputfile.txt` every time or something??

Comment: why did not you check the return value of `fprintf()`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still new to coding. I didn't think I was returning anything. Are you talking about the function?

Comment: Please check [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf), specially the return value part. :-)

Comment: I checked the return value and it's returning 81. Doesn't that mean 81 characters were suppose to be printed?

Comment: Yes.  Try running a fflush immediately after the writes.  Also, check the return value from fclose.

Comment: I'm still very confused because I ran it again and it worked.. it printed...
And then I ran it again and it's not working anymore. 
I tried deleting the pre-existing output file from running it before and tried running it again... but it's not working again....

Comment: Oh Oh Oh using fflush worked!

Comment: Is fflush necessary when using fprintf multiple times?? And thank you so much!!

Comment: No - it appears likely that your code is not getting to the close or the close is not working because fp is trashed.  fflush should not be needed - it was just a diagnostic step.

Comment: You're right! It was still running so I didn't notice there was an error but it says the fclose is ambiguous. I'll try to fix that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just to leave a comment if anyone comes to this question because they're experiencing the same problem, my problem didn't have anything to do with fclose being ambiguous. I just never got out of a for loop. Rookie mistake...